# JXL Won't Allow Excel 2007 Extensions

Tags: java, excel, excel-2007, jxl

I am using JXL to write an Excel report. Everything works fine if I use the .XLS extension. However, when I use the .XLSM extension, the report fails to load when I try to open it. I get the message "Excel cannot open the file 'TestExcel.xlsm' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file". Below is a simplified version of what I am doing. As mentioned, it works if you change the filePath to use .XLS instead.

```
String filePath = "C:\\Users\\Rachel\\Desktop\\TestExcel.xlsm";
File excelFile = new File(filePath);

WritableWorkbook book = Workbook.createWorkbook(excelFile);
WritableSheet sheet = book.createSheet("Test Sheet", 0);

sheet.addCell(new Label(0, 0, "Testing..."));

book.write();
book.close();
```

I am using Excel 2007 to open the file. If I create a new workbook in Excel, save it as xlsm, close it, and then open it, Excel opens it correctly. Does anyone know how to make the JXL file open correctly? I cannot switch to Apache POI or anything, I have to use JXL.

Comment: Prior to the first line of your code, could you rename your file to `TestExcel.xls`, open it, process it, close it, and rename it back to `TestExcel.xlsm`?  Or, if you don't need the macros in the code, save it without the m in the first place.

Comment: If I run the XLS code, if I rename the file using XLSM, it won't work. However, if I do a "Save As" and save it as XLSM, it will open.

Comment: So I am wondering if Excel does something special to the file when you "Save As" an XLSM. Something that JXL does not do.

Comment: If the first part of my suggestion didn't work, there's supposed to be some [box you can check](http://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=8962).  I haven't dealt with JXL directly, but I know programs of the sort.

Comment: Oh, I misread your comment. Did you mean like adding "excelFile.renameTo(new File("C:\\Users\\Rachel\\Desktop\\TestExcel2.xlsm"));" as the last line of the code? If so, no luck.

Comment: I just picked apart a xlsm (you can open it if you rename it to .zip) and it seems like the only difference is that there's a `.bin` file corresponding to the visual basic project in there.

Comment: Also, you may want to try your question at [the Yahoo group](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/JExcelApi/) for this library.  It looks like it's still fairly active.  Part of the problem may be that this library hasn't been updated in a while.

Comment: I posted on the group. I'll forward the answers here.